# What does the '@' symbol do in JavaScript multiline comments?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

Just really curious after I was poking around the Muuri source code and saw this everywhere:

```
var htmlCollectionType = '[object HTMLCollection]';
var nodeListType = '[object NodeList]';

/**
 * Check if a value is a node list
 *
 * @param {*} val
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
export default function isNodeList(val) {
  var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(val);
  return type === htmlCollectionType || type === nodeListType;
}
```

@param and @returns don't seem to actually do anything (I think), but they ARE highlighted differently. In fact, if you look at the code in git they're highlighted [as though they're not comments](https://github.com/haltu/muuri/blob/master/src/utils/isNodeList.js).

Is this some JavaScript syntax I'm unaware of? What's going on here? I would love to know.

Comment: They are comments and provide description about parameters accepted and return value by function `isNodeList`. Your function returns `boolean value` and it  accepts paramter of all DT which is indicated by `*`.

Answer (score 19):

This is just utilisting [JSDoc comments](https://jsdoc.app/). The syntax is influenced by Java which has JavaDoc comments as part of the standard. In short, the comment is documenting what a function or method does and it has slightly special syntax - it is a block comment that starts with `/**` instead of merely `/*` to differentiate it from a normal block comment and you can use some annotations to denote different meanings:

- `@param` means this is a parameter.

  - The value inside `{}` denotes the type of the parameter - in this case `*` means "any", but you to document something like `@param {string}` or `@param {number}`
  - the `val` is the name of the parameter that the function uses.
  - you can optionally add a description for the parameter e.g., something like `@param {*} val - used for foo and bar`
- the `@return` documents the return of the function.

  - the value inside `{}` is the type again. In this case, a boolean.
  - you can still optionally add a comment for the return value, for example: `@returns {Boolean} true if correct, false if incorrect`

There are more things you can document using JSDoc syntax, like `@copyright` to specify a license or `@throws` to declare what are the expected exceptions that some code can throw. Some syntax is specific for functions or methods, other for objects or even whole files.

All in all, it's an attempt to standardise the descriptions left in files. You don't *need* to do anything with the comment but you can also use tools that read the comments and act on them - some like [Tern.js](https://ternjs.net/) will read the comments and try to check if your code conforms, e.g., if you have

```js
/**
 * @param {number} bar
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function foo(bar) {}
```

and you call `foo("abc")` then you might get a warning by the tool that you should be passing a number. Or if you do `foo(123).replace("a", "b")` you can get a warning that you're trying to use string methods on what should be a boolean.

Other tools might instead just crawl your JS files and generate documentation. Java does this with JavaDoc - you can generate the documentation for your methods and classes automatically basing it on the JavaDoc comments. You would get a documentation [in the official Java style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) which means any documentation will be consistent.

Comment: In some tooling `@type` can be used to provide type-checked JavaScript as well.